# hide last element of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How to hide the last index of an array as I want to hide the label and show the input when user clicks on add button . Couldn't find help . Here is my code:-

```
<tr ng-repeat="personalDetail in personalDetails">
    <td> 
        <label ng-show="lab[$index]=true" for="settings" > {{personalDetail.Sname}}</label>
        <input ng-show="lab[$index]=false" type="text" ng-model="personalDetail.Sname" />
    </td>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary addnew pull-right btn-space" ng-click="addNew($index)" value=" Add New">
```

And my angular code :

```
$scope.addNew = function(val) {
   $scope.personalDetails.push({
      'Sname': "",
      'Settings': "",
   });
   var ind = $scope.personalDetails.length - 1;
   $("label[data-val='" + ind + "']").hide();
   $("input[data-val='" + ind + "']").show();
   $scope.PD = {};
};
```

Comment: Try use `$last` directive in `ng-repeat`.

Comment: you can use $last

Comment: Thank you for the answer.can u please explain it a littile ?

Comment: $last is part of the angular ng-repeat Special properties that are exposed on the local scope of each template instance.
Is is a boolean value that is true in and only the current iterated item is the last one.
Please have a look at [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<tr ng-repeat="personalDetail in personalDetails">
<td> 
<label ng-hide="$last" for="settings" > {{personalDetail.Sname}}</label>
<input ng-show="$last"  type="text" ng-model="personalDetail.Sname" />
</td>
<tr>
```

Reference: [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Answer (score 0):

Just check for **`$last`**,

```
   <td>  
    <label ng-show="lab[$index]==true" for="settings"> {{personalDetail.Sname}}</label>
    <input ng-show="lab[$index]==false" type="text" ng-model="personalDetail.Sname" />   
   </td>
```